# Finding a bijection that is not its inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $S$ be the set of binary strings of length $n$ i.e. each $x\in S$ is a string of zeroes and ones. Let $W(x)$ for $x\in S$ be the Hamming weight of $x$ i.e. number of ones in $x$. I am looking for a bijection $f:S\to S$ which

1. is NOT its inverse
2. "mixes" strings of a given weight to different weight classes. So this bijection doesn't work: Shift all strings of a weight class by a constant number because this would map strings of a given weight to strings of the same weight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a binary string of length n as a (row) vector of n components. That is, regard "110101" as the vector $(1,1,0,1,0,1)$. Now take an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ consisting of 0's and 1's whose determinant is an odd number.

Using this we can construct a bijection $f:S\to S$ by the following method:
$ f(x) = xA\pmod 2$ here $xA$ means multiplying the row vector $x$ by the matrix $A$ getting a new row vector, and then mod 2 means replacing all ODD numbers in the result by 1 and evens by 0, getting a binary string. This will be a bijection on $S$.
(In algebra jargon, this is an invertible linear transformation on a finite dimensional vector space over the field of 2 elements).

The choice of matrices $A$ gives you many bijections

Comment: I think finding one such $A$ is the main task. If $A$ is a permutation matrix, its determinant is an odd number and finding such an $A$ that satisfies $(1)$ and $(2)$ is the objective of the question.

Comment: Any  triangular matrix with 1's in the diagonal will do.

Comment: But for any such $A$, how can we know $f$ is not its inverse?

Comment: From the vast collection of such $A$ you can find easily locaate a matrix that is not its inverse. For example the matrix with all 1's at and above the diagonal, and zeros below the diagonal. No need to calculate inverse: simply check  for some standard basis vector $e_i$ that  $A (Ae_i)\ne e_i$